# jQuery $.post() inside w2ui .reload() makes TEXTAREA silently lose focus in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

**Note**: *this question is probably too specialized. The solution (if I ever find one) is unlikely to help anyone but myself. Nonetheless, I believe the* workaround *described below to apply to several borderline Chrome/jQuery focus loss scenarios.*

## Scenario:

I have an input TEXTAREA to enter some text.

Meanwhile, a timer makes periodical AJAX calls to the server (one per minute).

## What happens:

In **Firefox**, everything is hunky dory and the user can type away to his heart's content.

On **Chrome**, when the AJAX request fires, the input focus is lost. It goes... nowhere, apparently. `window.activeElement` returns nothing, and the cursor indeed disappears from the textarea, until the user clicks it again with the mouse.

## What I expected:

Well, for the focus to stay there.

## Attempts:

**One** - I have tried setting an event handler on the textarea's `[.focusout()][1]`, only to discover that the event does not fire. It *does* fire when **the user** clicks somewhere else, but that doesn't help.

**Two** - I have then tried a less elegant - say rather, brutal - approach:

```
var hasFocus = document.activeElement;
if (hasFocus) {
    var focusKeeper = window.setInterval(function(){
        hasFocus.focus(); // JUST. STAY. THERE.
        $(hasFocus).css("background-color", "red");
    }, 10);
}
```

The field goes red, so the handler *is* firing at least. Except that the focus does not come back. It's just as if Chrome isn't even *trying*.

Again, everything works as expected in Firefox. I'll try next on Safari to confirm whether this is a Webkit-related thing.

## Research and more attempts:

I've found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968045/jquery-textarea-loses-focus-after-playing-sound-notification) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074347/focus-not-working-in-safari-or-chrome) on how to overcome focus loss, or [how to set the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075867/setting-focus-on-textfield-after-refreshing-another-div-using-ajax) in the first place, even [on newly created fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433742/set-focus-to-field-in-dynamically-loaded-div) (which mine isn't), but my case seems [different enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347149/cant-set-focus-to-input-in-chrome-extension) that they either offered no clue, or just plain didn't work. The documentation states that

```
element.focus();
```

is necessary and sufficient, yet sufficient quite clearly it is not. Someone has suggested setting focus [using a zero-delay timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074347/focus-not-working-in-safari-or-chrome); I tried, but this did not seem to help.

Could this be related to the fact that Chrome maybe runs XHR requests in a different process, so that the "focus" is going to the hidden XHR window? (Haven't tried with the `--process-per-site` commandline switch, it just occurred to me - I will now give it a try).

Could this be a bug? There *was* something like it, but bug 27868 was related to [Flash objects](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27868), not TEXTAREAs - that's a completely different animal AFAIK.

The strange thing is that this behaviour (or one amazingly similar) was noted [**on Firefox**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571919) and the bug reporter says explicitly, *focus should remain on the same input control like* **in other browsers**, so he did *not* observe it on Chrome.

## JSFiddle - *not* exhibiting the behaviour, thus supplying a clue

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byz3qh3y/1/), and... it works. So the issue seems to be more with the function called in the timer, which is a [w2ui](http://w2ui.com/web/) grid.reload(). I still do not understand **why the focus doesn't come back using `focus()`**, as it should.

## Acceptable workaround

Inspired by amphetamachine's comment, I've tried combining several of the tricks in the posts above. I've come up with a combination that works... sort of.

The elements needed (whichever I remove, the trick stops working) are:

- re-set the focus manually where it was
- do this inside a setInterval timer
- blur the focus before re-setting it
- unset and reset the focus inside a short, **but not zero**, setTimeout delay.

  ```
  // Save focus.
  hasFocus   = document.activeElement;

  w2ui.myGrid.reload(function() { // Callback, called after reloading.
      // If there was no focus, we just return.
      if (hasFocus) {
          // We DON'T do anything directly, but use setTimeout.
          window.setTimeout(
              function() {
                  // And before setting the focus, we truly remove it.
                  hasFocus.blur();
                  hasFocus.focus();
              }, 5); // A timeout of 0 does not work.
      }
  });
  ```

The "con" of this solution is that the cursor visually "shivers", and any key that was pressed during the second part of the [grid.reload()](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.reload), after the unknown event that loses the Chrome focus, will of course get lost.

Comment: Iserni.. can you make small fiddle to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `I have tried setting an event handler on the textarea's .focusout()` -- Have you tried `.blur()`?

Comment: I made a JSFiddle but I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Could you verify that this is what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/61akgoe7/

The output is in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Obsolete: just update the libraries.

The strange behaviour disappeared by **upgrading w2ui to 1.4.2** on the latest Chrome (actually, I did not try on previous Chromes because I didn't think to keep copies of the previous versions).